# Pandoc formatting on PDF

Tags: formatting, pandoc

So I'm writing a book in markdown and using pandoc to convert it into PDF.
The problem I'm facing is with the formatting. I can easily make all h1 headings have a line break beforehand and it's pretty easy. The problem comes with h2, h3, etc.

There are times where I include various subheadings and after exporting to PDF I notice that some pages END of the subheading, which of course looks completely unprofessional. I could just change that on a case-by-case basis but that would be very inefficient for editing a 400-page book.

How can I make it so that the exported PDF will make sure there is text after any subheading and if not, place the subheading on the next page?

Answer (score 1):

> some pages END of the subheading

That's what's called a "widow" in typography.

Pandoc by default [uses LaTeX to generate the PDF](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#creating-a-pdf). Thus googling "avoid widow LaTeX" [turns up this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4152/how-do-i-prevent-widow-orphan-lines).

You can apply setting like these with pandoc for example like:

```
header-includes: |
  \widowpenalty10000
```